# Function for Twitter created_at

Tags: javascript, twitter

Does anyone have a javascript function that converts the created_at time stamp to the current twitter display requirement? I've found a few examples but none of them convert the created_at data from this

```
Sun Nov 17 17:09:13 +0000 2013
```

into this

```
17/11/2013 17:09 (as per the current twitter requirement(s))
```

You'd think twitter would provide an example.